# Getting 'name' attributes with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source_code = """<a href="#" name="One"></a>
                 <a href="#" name="Two"></a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)

print soup.a['name']   #prints 'One'
```

Using BeautifulSoup, i can grab the first name attribute which is `one`, but i am not sure how i can print the second, which is `Two`

Anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read [the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). There you can see that `soup.find_all` returns a list
so you can iterate over the list and, for each element, extract the tag you are looking for. So you should do something like (not tested here):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
for item in soup.find_all('a'):
    print item['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

To get any `a` child element other than the first, use `find_all`. For the second `a` tag:

```
print soup.find_all('a', recursive=False)[1]['name']
```

To stay on the same level and avoid a deep search, pass the argument: `recursive=False`

Comment: if i try this with INPUT instead of A, i get an Out of Range Error.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the tags of "a":

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> aTags = BeautifulSoup(source_code).findAll('a')
>>> for tag in aTags: print tag["name"]
... 
One
Two
```

Comment: @vjgaero Kindly close the question by [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it worked for you.